# JQuery __proto__ array messing up GET request?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a JQuery GET request to get data from an RScript running on a separate local server (using `plumber`). If I `console.log` the data, it returns like it should, but it also returns a "__proto__" array that contains (what looks like) 50 random functions (snippet below is what is console.log'd, with __Proto__ collapsed).

```
0:{Name: "Frank", Salary: 9800}
1:{Name: "Danny", Salary: 7700}
2:{Name: "Charlie", Salary: 5000}
3:{Name: "Ian", Salary: 4800}
4:{Name: "DJ", Salary: 4300}
5:{Name: "Logan", Salary: 4300}
6:{Name: "Jorge", Salary: 3800}
7:{Name: "Salvador", Salary: 3700}
8:{Name: "Jason", Salary: 3600}
9:{Name: "Chet", Salary: 3000}
length:10
__proto__: Array(0)
```

When I try adding just one of the names to my webpage, it works fine:

`$orders.append('<li>Name: ' + orders[0].Name + '</li>')` returns "Frank"

but when I try to post all names, it appends several "Name: undefined":

```
$.each(orders, function(i, order) {
                $orders.append('<li>P: ' + order.Name + '</li>');
            });
```

​Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong with the `$.each` function (I'm new to frontend stuff), or does it have to do with the "__proto__" array? Full code:

```
$(function (){

    var $orders = $('#orders');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'my/API/URL',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(order) {
            // console.log('Success', order);
            $.each(orders, function(i, order) {
                $orders.append('<li>P: ' + order.PlayerName + '</li>');
            });
            // $orders.append('<li>P: ' + orders[0].Name + '</li>');
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('Error you jabroni');
        }

    })
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `'s'` to params success. Because you foreach `orders`, not `order`

Should be:

```
success: function(orders) {
    // console.log('Success', orders);
    $.each(orders, function(i, order) {
        $orders.append('<li>P: ' + order.Name + '</li>');
    });
},
```